# CakePHP3.6: Paginator returns zero results despite find() functioning as usual

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Super confused by this; just using the standard baked templates for CRUD access to my models. I'm migrating this project from a much older version of cake, but again, so far I'm just using the stock baked controllers & templates.

```
/**
      * Index method
      *
      * @return \Cake\Http\Response|void
      */
     public function index() {
        $this->paginate = [
                'contain' => ['Associated1', 'Associated2', 'AssociatedEtc']
        ];
        $myModels = $this->paginate($this->MyModel);  // returns zero results
        $myModels_found = $this->MyModel->find('all'); // finds everything
        $this->set(compact('model'));
     }
```

The [CookBook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate) information describes implementing Paginator in a completely different way than the controllers are initially baked with (and, having tried the implementation described there, got the exact same result).

Importantly, as in `$myModel_found`, if I just retrieve records via `$model->find()` everything is returned as usual, so there's no trouble with connecting to the data layer.

How do I configure Paginator such that it actually retrieves my records?

**UPDATE**

After a little more delving, I've discovered that the Paginator is only returning zero results for models with unassociated associations (ie. a row in the table `Model1` that has 0 or null for `model2_id` etc. isn't returned. Even  if I remove the `contain` condition, this behavior persists.

Comment: Please, show your associations. Which strategy do you use for them? I mean if you use joins (for hasMany) and use INNER, you get what is expected.

Answer (score -1):

**Till sometimes ago, even i was stucked in the same situation. In my controller, i have:

**
/**

```
 * Index method
 *
 * @return \Cake\Http\Response|void
 */
public function index()
{
    $query = $this->request->query('query');
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Customers', 'Drivers'],
        'limit'=>200,
        'order'=>[
            'pick_date'=>'desc'
        ]
    ];
    if(!empty($query)){
            $this->paginate = [
                'conditions'=>[
                    'destination LIKE' => '%'.$query.'%',
                    'starting_point LIKE' => '%'.$query.'%'
                    ]
            ];
        } 
    $rides =$this->paginate($this->Rides);
    $this->set(compact('rides'));
}
```

**The mistake i had made was in my view file:**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Customer</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?= $this->Form->control('customer_id',array('class'=>'form-control input-circle', 'options'=>$customers, 'label'=>false)) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The spelling of 'customer_id' was wrong in my case and thus the result was not getting displayed in the view table. But now, it is working all right.

**Please check all the spellings of the associated columns names.**

**If I am mistaken anywhere, please don't mind. I am a learner in CakePHP 3.**

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this doesn't address my problem; the views and controller are baked by cake, there are no typos.